# OpenLayers ModifyFeature for multiple layers

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

Is it possible to configure the ModifyFeature control to edit features in multiple layers?

Comment: @drnextgis, we encourage people to wait for some time before accepting an answer--at least a few days--because alternative replies often emerge. Nobody should be in a rush to accept the first answer they get, but we hope that eventually they will accept *some* answer if it successfully responds to their question.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should create ModifyFeature controls for each layer. It is impossible to set multiple layers within one control.

Comment: What version of OL are you using? In the latest version at this time, ModifyFeature only accepts a single layer.

Comment: I have the same challenge. I want my user to be able to edit the feature on this drawlayer, but also to allready existing features loaded in another layer. Can I use one panel button to enable the modify controls on all the layers? Or wouldn't that work?